# Circle with inner rings of equal area?

Tags: shapes, mathematics

I'd like to create a circle with rings of equal **area** (as opposed to rings of equal *thickness*). The inner ring ends up being a filled circle, and there are two extra rings, for a total of three(3).Here is what I have, which doesn't satisfy the constraint, but just to give an idea:

[image]

I `selected`, `filled`, `shrink`, `filled`, `shrink` and `filled` (BGR). I could try taking into account the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/270287) beforehand, but I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this, either with *Gimp* or other software used in graphic design?

Comment: If you want the actual area then you're going to need to use math.

Comment: Yes, you can draw circles with The Gimp. But you'll have to ask this on Mathematics.se to get help with the math part.

Comment: Thank you both, I included the link to the math Q in my OP for context; but the angle was I don't know software like _Illustrator_ and people often talk about substracting shapes etc... I thought maybe something along those lines was possible. I know this can be programmed...

Comment: this really depends on your definition of simple. In my mind easiest way is to script it, but you can use the square root spiral. Or just use mathematica.

Comment: Perhaps is simpler to you use Inkscape to draw, resize (using the diameters calculated following the answer of JoKnowBody) and align the circles.

Comment: Thanks joojaa, Paolo Gibellini. This is most likely compounded by my lacking Illustrator knowledge. I thought if I had a circle and know I want 3 rings inside, then the area has to be pi * r * r/3 per. I thought I had a status area and I could substract by "pixel count" or something like that. I would substract 2/3 from the original shape, then 1/2 of the remainder. Did I have too much coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with the disc in the middle, you know its radius in pixels: `R_red`. The area `A` of the disc is

`A=pi*R_red**2`.

`A` is also the area of the green and blue area, respectively. Therefore, the outer radius of the green ring belongs to a disc with area `2*A`.

`R_green = sqrt(2*A/pi))`, and consequently

`R_blue=sqrt(3*A/pi))`.

So, `R_green` is `sqrt(2)` times bigger than `R_red`, and `R_blue` is `sqrt(3)` times bigger than `R_red`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that is the method employed and that's how I approached trying to make this with _Processing_. Then I realized starting from the center going outward doesn't make it very predictable in terms of layout/design; someone provided me with a version that starts with a fixed circle size and draws inward. See [here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8119/dividing-a-circle-into-rings-of-equal-area-howto).

Comment: Of course, if you specify the number of rings and the outer radius you can reorder the formula.

Comment: Thank you, yes indeed. I consider "calculating it" is a valid answer to my Q; I'll deduce that GD core software doesn't offer such facilities. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Some one did ask a similar question on Mathematics SE -> [How to divide a circle into 9 rings / 1 inner circle with the same area?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270287/how-to-divide-a-circle-into-9-rings-1-inner-circle-with-the-same-area)

You will have to adjust the equation a bit.

Comment: Thank you! Please note I had included this very link in my Q.

Comment: Really great question, got my gears turning. You welcome, sorry I can't help with GIMP (I've never used it).  I had the same thought DA01 had, so I figure I see if there as already an answer.

Comment: If you're into that sort of things you'll enjoy these [implementations](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8119/dividing-a-circle-into-rings-of-equal-area-howto#Item_10). I also failed 10px short of doing it right in this case in some sister language [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwWKYv)lol. But I was looking to learn something about how to approach the problem using the GD software...

Answer (score -2):

in adobe illustrator :
draw the circle in any size you want , then copy it.
after that past in the same place and use the selection tool (v) to re-size it with keep clicking on alt with shift buttons.
copy the new one and past it in the place and then click on Ctrl+D 2 times.

Comment: Thank you, but this would be arbitrary. There is a mathematical relationship between the rings and it must be expressed. With prior calculations, of course you would know exactly the radius of each circle so you could scale down accordingly. I was looking for assistance and feedback in that respect from the software...